# Can I set state property as a callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it OK to set state in a callback? The code actually works but I need to know if it is fits good practices on setting state.

`this.setState(this.props.onSuccess(data), () => {loading: false})`

Comment: Please post the body of the `onSuccess` method. Also, this question doesn't really belong to SO as it requires opinionated answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be more effective:

```
this.props.onSuccess(data) && this.setState({ loading: false });
```

I don't think the pattern you have used is something very common at all.

Comment: Thanks. This code looks better than my example and works as expected!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to set the state on the hook itself:

```
onSuccess(data) {
 // ...
 this.setState({loading: false})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// WRONG

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + props.count})
doSomething(this.state.count)
```

// RIGHT

```
this.setState((prevState,props) => ({counter: prevState.count + props.count}))
```

- Dont rely on current state when computing